# JSON [{"non_field_errors": ["Invalid data"]}]} Django Rest Framework

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have some serializer where I have some elements and want it to POST it when I create POST method for InvoiceDictionarySerializer. Dont have any idea how to make it works properly. Any suggestions?

My code looks as follow:

```
class InvoiceDictionaryElementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = InvoiceDictionaryElement
    fields = (
        'name', 'unit', 'quantity', 'value'
    )


class InvoiceDictionarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    invoice_elements = InvoiceDictionaryElementSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceDictionary
        fields = (
            'name', 'is_active', 'invoice_elements')
```

and my request for JSON:

```
{
"name": "invoice", 
"is_active": true, 
"invoice_elements":  [{
        "name": "name", 
        "unit": "12", 
        "quantity": "15.00", 
        "value": "7.00"
    }]
```

}

got error:

```
{"invoice_elements": [{"non_field_errors": ["Invalid data"]}]}
```

On my conslote output i have 400 error (bad request). Dont know that the syntax for JSON is bad or what?

Comment: how are you doing the request? can you post the code/command?

Comment: im using postman and code is pasted already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `invoice_elements` is a list of elements, you need to specify `many=True`

```
class InvoiceDictionarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    invoice_elements = InvoiceDictionaryElementSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceDictionary
        fields = (
            'name', 'is_active', 'invoice_elements')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ...
```

[You should also implement](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations) `.create()` or `.update()` methods of the serializer that handle saving multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
example_entry = serializers.CharField(required=True/False)
```

Issue is here at serializer fields. Configure it with right flags.